# Problems in getting SublimeLinter to work

Tags: sublimetext2

I need help getting the [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/) to work.

I have installed the SublimeLinter using the package installer. However I cant see the lint working in my js files. Also when I do <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (linux) I only see the following command for linter 'Sublime Linter : Extract Annotations'.

I don't see the other commands for running the linter.

Any Ideas what is wrong?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: Du you have node installed?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? was it nodeJs?

Comment: Perhaps related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294119/sublime-linter-not-working-in-windows

Answer (score 2):

You have to install nodejs from the repos.

If nodejs isn't installed in `/usr/local/bin/node` you have to set a symbolic link to this place:

- touch /usr/local/bin/node
- ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node

The above worked for me on debian/crunchbang

Alternatively you can change the sublime user settings for linter(ps haven't tested this option)

```
"sublimelinter_executable_map":
{
    "javascript": "/usr/bin/nodejs"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

1. Be sure your files are using the Javascript syntax.
2. The linter runs automatically (check the package settings).
3. Open the console to see any errors.
4. Check the [documentation](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter#javascript-based-linters) to configure Javascript linters