# Sublime Linter not working in Windows

Tags: sublimetext2

As the title says.
The linter doesnt seem to work at all for me in Windows. I have tried it with javascript and php files with the correct syntax set.
Im following Jeffery Ways tutorial here -> https://tutsplus.com/lesson/sublime-linter/

I have installed package control,
SublimeLinter and nothing, removed it
installed sublimelinter beta and nothing too.

Any help please

Comment: Check Console window for possible errors

Comment: Did you install [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) then restart sublime?

Comment: @Mikko no, how do i do this?

Comment: @d_rail no havent installed node.js. I have just done what was mentioned above.

Comment: `Ctrl + ~` opens the console, however node.js is a requirement.

Answer (score 9):

From [SublimeLinter's github page](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter):

"If you plan to edit files that use a Javascript-based linter (Javascript, CSS), your system must have a Javascript engine installed... On Windows, you must install the Javascript engine Node.js, which can be downloaded from the Node.js site."

[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

Install it like a normal Windows application.  Close Sublime and restart.  Linting should be working.

Comment: That worked for the javascript, but how do i get it working for the php now?

Comment: PHP must be a different issue.  Any relevant errors in the console?  What have you tried to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to point the SublimeLinter to your PHP executable file in the SublimeLinter.sublime-settings.

Change this option:

```
"sublimelinter_executable_map":
{
    "php": "C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.3.13\\php.exe"
},
```

Edit:

See this link for more help

http://fuzzytolerance.info/blog/2012/05/14/2012-05-15-getting-sublimelinter-running-on-windows/

Answer (score 1):

In order to get SublimeLint linting js files, I had to follow the instructions here and install this additional plugin:

(I didn't need to follow the 'Linter configuration' step)

https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-jshint#linter-installation